# Ruby-Rails in Docker exits after docker run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have created a Dockerfile [based on the description](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/install-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu/) to create a rails application in Linux. Currently, I have two problems with the current setting:

First, I get the error or warning after every RUN command starting with the environment variable $shell. The error looks like this:

```
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Second, my container stops directly after starting it with

```
docker run -d --name rails rails:test
```

My current docker file looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir /usr/src/rails
WORKDIR /usr/src/rails

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y yarn

RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
RUN useradd -G rvm rails

ENV shell /bin/bash -l -c
#RUN . /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
RUN echo ". /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN $shell "rvm requirements"
RUN $shell "rvm install ruby"
RUN echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" >> ~/.gemrc
RUN $shell "gem install rails"
RUN $shell "ruby -v" && $shell "rails -v"

USER rails
EXPOSE 3000

#CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The solution with the `$shell` variable I found on another website. Without the command `/bin/bash -l -c` the build process will fail. The command `rvm` or `gem` will be unknown. The mentioned command will be used as a wrapper around the real command inside the quotes. I do not really understand why this is necessary. If I create a docker container and execute the commands like they are in the Dockerfile, then everything works fine. Why it is not working as I execute the command inside of the Dockerfile script?

Since I use the wrapper command, everything works well, but I get this error or warning message mentioned above. The image will be made, so this is more like a minor problem. The main problem is, that my container doesn't start. If I type the command `docker run -d rails:test` the container will be exited directly after. I do not really understand why. Does anyone have some explanations?

Comment: Don't install RVM in docker. Use [a docker image with Ruby preinstalled](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby).

Comment: RVM is kind of fussy in that it needs a login shell, so you may have to work around that limitation using the `/bin/bash -l -c` wrapper.

Comment: docker website itself has a good documentation on setting up a rails project via docker.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/
As previous comments suggested directly you can use a docker image with Ruby preinstalled.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal That's actually what I used in the beginning and I wasn't able to make it run. The error I got from this scenario was 'standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"'.

Comment: @anothermh: This is just an ruby image, right? I try to build a rails container to get to know how rails and ruby really works, because I try to archive how Redmine is working. The goal I gonna try to achieve is, to build own ruby/rails modifications for Redmine.