# How do I get rvm install to download from the right url?

Tags: ruby, docker, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 3.2.2 on my container using the following line in my docker file:

`RUN bash -lc 'rvm install ruby-3.2.2'`

But when it comes there, it fails with the following error:

`curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404  The requested url does not exist(22): 'https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/ruby-3.2.2.tar.bz2' Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/ruby-3.2.2.tar.bz2`

The obvious reason is that there is no ruby-3.2.2.tar.bz2 under https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/

Instead there are ruby-3.2.2.tar.gz, ruby-3.2.2.tar.xz and ruby-3.2.2.zip

How do I get it to point at one of these?

I was expecting it to install ruby 3.2.2 by fetching one of ruby-3.2.2.tar.gz, ruby-3.2.2.tar.xz or ruby-3.2.2.zip

Comment: Can you just use `curl` to download the file you need?  Using a version manager like `rvm` can be complicated in Docker, but since a Docker image only runs a single application, it only needs a single language runtime, and just installing it directly might be easier.

Comment: @joonu-thomas Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer to use a [docker image with Ruby preinstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107349/ruby-rails-in-docker-exits-after-docker-run), instead of using `rvm`, and start the `Dockerfile` with the Ruby base image, such as:

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2
```

In case you need to install Ruby with `rvm`, you can use this example of `Dockerfile`, which contains the main steps to install ruby with rvm:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install ruby-3.2.2"
```